# What's the intrinsic value of stocks

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, price

I am a financial noob. I wonder what are some intrinsic value of stocks. While purchasing a stock, I expect that the price of it will go up, and I'll sell it to gain the price difference. However, the price is determined by the mass, which also applies to currencies or such. If no one wants the stock tomorrow, its price will be zero. **What, then, contributes to the price of stocks, other than the expectation for the price to grow?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a stock doesn't pay dividends, then why is the stock worth anything?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/51976/if-a-stock-doesnt-pay-dividends-then-why-is-the-stock-worth-anything)

Comment: Yes! I did not even know the word "dividend". Thank you so much.